# Null conditional operator to "nullify" array element existence

Tags: c#, arrays, null, c#-6.0, null-propagation-operator

The new C# 6.0 null-conditional operator is a handy vehicle for writing more concise and less convoluted code. Assuming one has an array of customers, then you could get null instead of a length if `customers` is null using this (examples from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx)):

```
int? length = customers?.Length;
```

Similarly you could get null instead of a customer with this:

```
Customer first = customers?[0];
```

And for a more elaborate expression, this yields null if `customers` is null, the first customer is null, or the first customer's `Orders` object is null:

```
int? count = customers?[0]?.Orders?.Count();
```

**But then there is the interesting case of the non-existent customer** that the null-conditional operator does not seem to address. We saw above that a *null* customer is covered, i.e. if an entry in the `customers` array is null. But that is quite distinct from a *non-existent* customer, e.g. looking for customer `5` in a 3-element array or customer `n` in a 0-element list. (Note that the same discussion applies to Dictionary lookup as well.)

It seems to me that the null-conditional operator is focused exclusively on negating the effects of a NullReferenceException; IndexOutOfRangeException or KeyNotFoundException are alone, exposed, cowering in the corner, and needing to fend for themselves! I submit, that in the spirit of the null-conditional operator, it should be able to handle those cases as well... which leads to my question.

Did I miss it? Does the null-conditional provide any elegant way to truly cover this expression...

```
customers?[0]?.Orders?.Count();
```

...when there is no zeroth element?

Comment: "Null-conditional operator", not "exception globbing operator". Personally I'd consider unintuitive behavior if it bypasses OutOfIndexExceptions/KeyNotFoundException for nulls.

Comment: The `?.` operator simply wraps the code in `if (val != null) { ...//Continue }`. `IndexOutOfRangeException` can come from *anywhere*, and many classes do indeed throw it. An indexing operation also doesn't necessarily mean an *index lookup* in terms of traditional arrays, it's also used in dictionaries/lookups/etc. It wouldn't make sense for it to catch this kind of exception.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

No, because it is a **null**-conditional operator, not an **indexoutofrange**-conditional operator and is merely syntactic sugar to something like the following:

```
int? count = customers?[0]?.Orders?.Count();

if (customers != null && customers[0] != null && customers[0].Orders != null)
{
    int count = customers[0].Orders.Count();
}
```

You can see that if there is no zeroth customer, you will get your regular `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

One way you could work around it is to have an extension method that checks for the index and returns null if it doesn't exist:

```
public static Customer? GetCustomer(this List<Customer> customers, int index)
{
    return customers.ElementAtOrDefault(index); // using System.Linq
}
```

Then your check could be:

```
int? count = customers?.GetCustomer(0)?.Orders?.Count();
```

Comment: I actually did end up going with an extension method on `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` called `ElementAtOrNull` that operates in a similar fashion by returning `dictionary.ContainsKey(lookupValue) ? dictionary[lookupValue] : null`

Comment: It might be good to move the ElementAtOrDefault information closer to the top of the answer.  It looks like it is a standard function, and does exactly what the user wants.

Answer (score 16):

```
customers?.FirstOrDefault()?.Orders?.Count();
```

No zeroeth, no problem.

Comment: Don't fearoeth the zeroeth.

Comment: you found a sollution to replace the [0] to "FirstOrDefault", but the question was more genral, regarding [index], where index might be out of arrays bounds..

Answer (score 12):

If you want to get the nth element without having NullReference or IndexOutOfRange exceptions, you can use:

```
customers?.Skip(n)?.FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: This is the most elegant solution by far

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't support indexing safety because, when you get down to it, an indexer really is just syntactic sugar for any other type of method.

For example:

```
public class MyBadArray
{
    public Customer this[int a]
    {
        get
        {
            throw new OutOfMemoryException();
        }
    }
}

var customers = new MyBadArray(); 
int? count = customers?[5]?.Orders?.Count();
```

Should this be caught here? What if the exception was more sensible, similar to a KeyNotFoundException, but specific to the type of collection we're implementing? We'd have to continually update the `?.` functionality to keep up.

Further, `?.` does not catch exceptions. It prevents them.

`var customer = customers?[5];` is actually compiled as:

```
Customer customer = null;
if (customers != null)
    customer = customers[5];
```

Making it catch exceptions becomes exceptionally more difficult. For example:

```
void Main()
{
    var thing = new MyBadThing(); 
    thing.GetBoss()?.FireSomeone();
}

public class MyBadThing
{
    public class Boss
    {
        public void FireSomeone() 
        { 
            throw new NullReferenceException();
        }
    }
    public Boss GetBoss()
    {
        return new Boss();
    }
}
```

If it were simply catching exceptions, it would be written as :

```
Boss boss = customer.GetBoss();
try 
{
    boss.FireSomeone();
} catch (NullReferenceException ex) { 

}
```

Which would actually catch the exception within `FireSomeone`, rather than the null reference exception which would be thrown if boss were null.

The same bad-catching problem would be present if we were to catch index lookup exceptions, key not found exceptions, etc.

Comment: override operator [] with swallowing ArgumentOutRange exception should work.